# ¿Cómo habilitar TextInput al escribir en otro TextInpuit?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

buena tarde. Soy nuevo en React native y estoy realizando una app donde el proceso que quiero es que al momento es escribir en un TextInput un dato, se habilite un formulario, este formulario debe estar deshabilitado cuando inicie la app. Ya estuve investigando pero no encuentro alguna información. Me podrían apoyar guiar por favor en como realizar esto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar operadores ternarios para controlar el estado de visualización del formulario, te dejo un ejemplo en snack https://snack.expo.io/@reyandres10/74598f, si el link está malo te dejo el código también.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  const [visible,setVisible]=useState(false)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
        placeholder="Ingresa para mostrar el formulario"
        onChange={()=>setVisible(true)}
        style={styles.input}
        />{
          visible?
        <View>
        <TextInput
        placeholder="user"
        style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
        placeholder="password"
        style={styles.input}
        />
        </View>
          :null
        }
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  input:{
    width:200,
    height:20
  }
});
```